# MySQL: Return table names without using any of "show tables from database_name" or "select table_name from information_schema.tables" queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to return table names without using "show tables from database_name" or "select table_name from information_schema.tables" queries the reason of that:

1. I can't use "show tables from database_name" query because it returns a row set of table names with a fixed field name "Tables_database_name" and this is not acceptable in my code when the database name is too long -I am using DBExpress on Delphi and the column name can't be longer than 31 character-.
2. I can't use "select table_name from information_schema.tables" query because it is not supported with old MySQL I think older than 5.1

Please help if any body knows :

- How to change the resulted fixed column name of the "show tables from database_name".

or

- Any other query that returns the table names inside a specific database.

Comment: I can't help, but a +1 just for the fact that you've given reasons for wanting to avoid well known solutions.

Comment: Thanks, actually I am having this situation and I am trying to find out a workaround for it.

Comment: Why don't you update MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

> How to change the resulted fixed column name of the "show tables from database_name".

Seems like SHOW TABLES is a separate statement with fixed syntax:

```
SHOW [FULL] TABLES [{FROM | IN} db_name] [LIKE 'pattern' | WHERE expr]
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html

It is not a SELECT so you can not UNION with it or juggle with it in any form (change column names) so i guess answer to this quesiotn is: it is impossible.

> Any other query that returns the table names inside a specific database.

If you compare this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/show-tables.html

to this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html

It seems like only alternative to SHOW TABLES prior 5.0 was "mysqlshow" shell command

information_schema was introduced in MySql 5.0 and it was stable 8 years ago. So i guess you are trying to make your software compatible with very old versions.

---

What does this "DBExpress" do when column names are longer than 31 chars? does it truncate it or fails? Maybe you should state a question tagged "delphi" and "DBExpress" and ask how to bypass this limitation?

Comment: DBExpress raises an exception when column names are long.
On Delphi there is many solutions like using TSQLConnection of DBExpress and use the function TSQLConnection.GetTableNames but I was interested in the SQL solution of this issue.

Comment: I guess this is kinda why INFORMATION_SCHEMA was implemented. To allow doing such things with SQL without using non-standard commands like SHOW. I can't see a way this can be done without it.